# Export and backup section of code is not executing in python streamlit library

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, runtime-error, streamlit

I am making small mood tracker website using streamlit library of python. It also contains Database file which i imported via "import SQL_db" statement.

```
import streamlit as st
from datetime import date
import SQL_db
import json
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st
from datetime import date
import SQL_db
import sqlite3

mood_list = ["Happy", "Sad", "Angry", "Excited", "Anxious", "Relaxed", "Stressed", "Content", "Bored", "Energetic" 
]

# # Rest of the code...



#     database.close_db()
class MoodDatabase:
    def connect_db(self):
        self.conn_db = sqlite3.connect("moodtracker.db")  # Connect to SQLite database
        self.db = self.conn_db.cursor()  # Create a cursor object to interact with the database

    def backupData(self):
        # Export the mood_tracker table as a JSON file
        query = "SELECT * FROM mood_tracker"
        self.db.execute(query)
        rows = self.db.fetchall()

        data = []
        for row in rows:
            entry = {
                'id': row[0],
                'Date': row[1],
                'Time_Added': row[2],
                'Mood': row[3],
                'Journal': row[4]
            }
            data.append(entry)

        with open('backup.json', 'w') as file:
            json.dump(data, file, indent=4)

    def exportCSV(self):
        # Export the mood_tracker table as a CSV file
        query = "SELECT * FROM mood_tracker"
        df = pd.read_sql_query(query, self.conn_db)
        df.to_csv('backup.csv', index=False)

    def exportJSON(self):
        # Export the mood_tracker table as a JSON file
        query = "SELECT * FROM mood_tracker"
        df = pd.read_sql_query(query, self.conn_db)
        df.to_json('backup.json', orient='records')

    # Rest of the methods...

# Set the Streamlit app title
st.title("Mood Tracker")

# Get the current date and time
current_date = date.today()
current_time = current_date.strftime("%I:%M %p")

# Get user input for their mood
mood = st.selectbox("Select your mood", mood_list)

# Get user input for the reason for their mood
journal = st.text_area(f"Why do you feel {mood.lower()}?")

# Create a submit button
submitted = st.button("Submit")
# submitted = True
# Insert data into the database
database = SQL_db.MoodDatabase()

if submitted:
    database.connect_db()
    database.insertData(current_date, current_time, mood, journal)
    database.conversion()
    database.close_db()

    # Clear the mood selection and journal entry
    # mood = ""
    # journal = ""

    # Show a confirmation message
    st.success("Mood submitted successfully!")


# Rest of the code...

if submitted:
    
    # # Show a confirmation message
    # st.success("Mood submitted successfully!")

    # Add backup and export options
    st.write("---")
  
    st.subheader("Data Backup and Export")
    print("hello subheader\n")
   
    if submitted_connect:
        database.connect_db()
        database.backupData()
        database.close_db()
        st.success("Data backup successful!")

    submitted_export = st.button("Export as CSV")
    if submitted_export:
        database.connect_db()
        database.exportCSV()
        database.close_db()
        st.success("Data exported as CSV!")

    submitted_export_json = st.button("Export as json")
    if submitted_export_json:
        database.connect_db()
        database.exportJSON()
        database.close_db()
        st.success("Data exported as JSON!")
```

The given code is executing up to st.subheader(). It is also printing the hello subheader, but after this, it is not executing the backup and export sections of code, i.e., when I am clicking on any one of the three buttons, it is not showing any success message, nor is it creating files.It just refreshes the page as soon as I click on the export or backup button without producing any output. [Before clicking] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRfC8.jpg)[After clicking the export or backup button, nothing happened.] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/rerHo.jpg) .
Why code export and backup Data button not working or not showing any output.